# ServiceNow Midserver failover cluster using Azure VM

Tags: servicenow, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

How to configure failover for ServiceNow MidServer in Azure VMs.  Should i choose the option of Azure VMSS for failover ?
What options do we have for failover of ServiceNow in Azure VMs . Is it azure availability zones ?
Please help.

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does is solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we want to configure failover cluster option for servicenow's MidServer , we have to configure that option in the ServiceNow.com SaaS portal.  There we have to specify what is the name of the failover VM.  Hence the only option is to specify failover server name and keep it in different availability zone (for zone level redundancy) or availability set.

Answer (score 0):

All the options you think are good choices. But there are also differences between them. I'll show you the differences as I know and you choose one of them or combine them to match your requirement.

The virtual machine scale set is a group of load-balanced VMs. Due to its feature, when one instance failed, then it will not send the requests to the failed instance and balances the requests t other instances if the scale set has more then one instance. So it's not the failover for ServiceNow MidServer, but it can achieve the same destination.

[Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/manage-availability#use-availability-zones-to-protect-from-datacenter-level-failures) are unique physical locations within an Azure region. The physical separation of Availability Zones within a region protects applications and data from datacenter failures. Zone-redundant services replicate your applications and data across Availability Zones to protect from single-points-of-failure. I think it's the things that you mean failover for ServiceNow MidServer.

You can choose one of them. Or it will have higher availability if you combine both them.